# printf output for cross format specifier

Tags: c, printf

The below program is printing 123828749, 0.000000 but I expected 123828749, 123828749.0. From where it is getting 0.000000 ?

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    void main()

    {

        double x = 123828749.66;

        int y = x;

        printf("%d\n", y);

        printf("%lf\n", y);

    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second call to `printf` you are passing an `int`, but the format string is `%lf` which expects a floating point value to be passed. This invokes undefined behaviour.

If you want to treat `y` as a floating point value when you pass it to `printf`, you'll need an explicit conversion:

```
printf("%lf\n", (double)y);
```

Comment: Will it not do type conversion ?

Comment: No it won't. The compiler does not parse the format string. It relies on you to pass arguments of appropriate type.

Answer (score 1):

To answer more precisely to your question (even though David's answer is completely precise), when (at runtime) the format string gets parsed by `printf` function it expects `double` format. However, you supplied an `int` and since `int` is most likely not the same size as `double` (there is no indication that this is the case, though) your program read some junk memory and printed this unexpected result. This is where the zeroes came from.

Comment: Note: Different types may be passed by different means (memory stack vs. numeric processor FP stack) even if the _same_ size and result in UB such as `"0.000000"`.  Had OP used `printf("%le\n", y);`, more interesting output may have occurred.

Comment: I completely agree. What I said is just one of the possible explanations for this output.